# Fade in div onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys i have 2 divs with information inside of them and i want it so that when the user clicks on button 1/2 it shows the correct DIV. I have manged to get this far and make that work however i want to try and put an animation on them so it docent just quickly come up on the screen. So fading the text in and out when they click the button. I am not sure if there is a library for this as i have used AOS library before but that is for scrolling and not an on click function.

HTML:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="header1">Företagstelefoni</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="header2">Reklambyrå</button>

        <div class="parallax1" id="section_one" >
            <div class="row newtryh2">
                 ........
            </div>
       </div>

        <div class="parallax1" id="section_two">
            <div class="row newtryh2">
                 ........
            </div>
       </div>
```

JS:

```
$("#header1").click(function () {

    $("#section_one").show();
    $("#section_two").hide();
});
$("#header2").click(function () {

    $("#section_two").show();
    $("#section_one").hide();

});
```

CSS:

```
.parallax1 {
    padding-left: 30px;
        margin-top: 33px;
        display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/t5h1up21/3/)

So I'm just trying to add some animation like fading it in nicely so it doesn't snap onto the screen and fading it out. If anyone can help me out with this or knows any libraries out there such as AOS which works on a onclick that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: if you are already using jquery, why not use fadeIn() / fadeOut()? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

IE `$("#section_two").fadeIn('fast');`

https://jsfiddle.net/t5h1up21/5/

Conversely you can use [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)

**EDIT**

The function with callback would look like:

```
$("#section_two").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("#section_one").fadeIn('fast'); // Or whatever your selector is
});
```

Comment: Can i ask why on the fiddle the text like jumps up and down when you press the button?

Comment: A symptom of fadeOut... probably should be hiding immediately and only fading in

Comment: Also how would i use the fadeToggle? i am trying to add it in , as i think that would be the best bet, but now both my divs show

Comment: @AnthonyRivas thank you :) i think fadetoggle will be my best bet

Comment: Yes that is a separate issue .. You'll need to set a `fadeOut()` as a function with a `callback` of `fadeIn()` so it waits until the `fadeOut()` is complete before issuing the `fadeIn()`

Comment: Guessing i will need to post anther question in a bit if i cant figure it out

Comment: I added the callback to the end of my answer

Comment: @Zak i tried this on the fiddle but it dosent seem to work at all